Take two pencils of perpendicular hyperboloids, take their limits, and you get a hyperbolic paraboloid
Claim:

Let $\ell, m$ be two perpendicular lines in $\mathbb R^3$.  The pencil of hyperboloids of one sheet with axis $\ell$, and the pencil of hyperboloids of one sheet with axis $m$, both approach the same surface.  That surface is a hyperbolic paraboloid whose center is the intersection of $\ell$ and $m$.
(By axis I mean the unique axis of symmetry that does not intersect the hyperboloid.)

Proof sketch:
Each of the pencils can be parameterized by the equations
$$x^2 - y^2 + cz^2  = z + 1$$ and
$$y^2 - x^2 + cz^2  = - z - 1$$ up to affine similarity.  Take the limit as $c \to 0$, you get, in both cases $$x^2 - y^2 = z + 1$$ the hyperbolic paraboloid.
I believe the above is correct, but can't visualize this.  Is there a way to visualize this, demonstrate (or prove) it geometrically, or somehow see this intuitively?

Update
One insight: Let $p$ be a point on a smooth surface of degree 2 such that $p$ is a maximum in one plane and a minimum in another.  Then the Taylor series shows that a sufficiently small region around $p$ resembles a hyperbolic paraboloid.  Any point on the circle orthogonal to the hyperboloid's access in the plane including the center is a maximum in one plane and a minimum in another (perpendicular) plane.  Therefore, in the small, the surface near that point must resemble a hyperbolic paraboloid.
By taking the limit, we expand that small region larger and larger, and get, in the limit, a hyperbolic paraboloid.
Needed to show this argument works for both hyperboloids.
